# How to disable frontend registration in Magento

Tags: magento

As titled.

But still, users can login to the frontend, and administrator could create user account only in backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I got it worked. Refer to Hugues Solution, there are two amendments:

1. add app\etc\modules\Mycompany_All.xml

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0"?>
   > <config>
   >     <modules>
   >         <Mycompany_Registrationremove>
   >             <active>true</active>
   >             <codePool>local</codePool>
   >         </Mycompany_Registrationremove>
   >     </modules>
   > </config>
   > ```
2. modify the file: app/code/local/Mycompany/Registrationremove/etc/config.xml

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0"?>
   > <config>
   >     <modules>
   >         <Mycompany_Registrationremove>
   >             <version>0.1.0</version>
   >         </Mycompany_Registrationremove>
   >     </modules>
   >  <global>
   >         <rewrite>
   >             <mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_create>
   >                 <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/create/$#]]></from>
   >                 <to>/registrationremove/customer_account/create</to>
   >             </mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_create>
   >             <mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_createPost>
   >                 <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/createPost/$#]]></from>
   >                 <to>/registrationremove/customer_account/createPost</to>
   >             </mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_createPost>
   >         </rewrite>
   >     </global>
   >     <frontend>
   >         <routers>
   >             <mycompany_registrationremove>
   >                 <use>standard</use>
   >                 <args>
   >                     <module>Mycompany_Registrationremove</module>
   >                     <frontName>registrationremove</frontName>
   >                 </args>
   >             </mycompany_registrationremove>
   >         </routers>
   >     </frontend>
   > </config>
   > ```

Comment: Whoups, forgot the /etc/modules/Mycompany_All.xml  :)
And the createPost action

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility would be overloading the customer/account/create action and just redirect the user to the home page when this action is invoked.

In a first time, just do what was proposed by Ben V. It will remove the possibility to view the registration page.

Then, create a new module in which you will overload the AccountController.php.

1- Create a new folder in `app/code/local/` named Mycompany

2- Create a new folder in `app/code/local/Mycompany/` named Registrationremove

3- Create `app/code/local/Mycompany/Registrationremove/etc/`

4- Create `app/code/local/Mycompany/Registrationremove/etc/config.xml`

Copy and Paste in config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Registrationremove>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Registrationremove>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
             <mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_create>
                      <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/create/$#]]></from>
                      <to>/registrationremove/customer_account/create</to>
                 </mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_create>
                 <mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_createPost>
                     <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/createPost/$#]]></from>
                     <to>/registrationremove/customer_account/createPost</to>
                 </mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_createPost>
           </rewrite> 
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <registrationremove>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompany_Registrationremove</module>
                    <frontName>registrationremove</frontName>
                </args>
            </registrationremove>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

5- Create `app/code/local/Mycompany/Registrationremove/controllers`

6- Create `app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Registrationremove.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Registrationremove>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Registrationremove>
    </modules>
</config>
```

7- Create `app/code/local/Mycompany/Registrationremove/controllers/Customer/AccountController.php`

Copy and Paste in AccountController.php:

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';

class Mycompany_Registrationremove_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function createAction()
    {
      $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }

    public function createPostAction()
    {
      $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }

}
```

8- Create `app/code/local/Mycompany/Registrationremove/Helper/Data.php`

Copy and paste in Data.php:

```
class Mycompany_Registrationremove_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Now, when someone tries to access to customer/account/create/ it should be redirected to the home page.

Hope that helped :)

Hugues.

Comment: hi, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959131/how-to-disable-frontend-registration-in-magento/3995507#3995507

Comment: This worked. However, I put AccountController.php under `controllers/`, not `controllers/Customer/` as noted.

Comment: Worked for me too, but had to keep AccountController.php in `controllers/Customer/`, and rename the class to `Mycompany_Registrationremove_Customer_Accountcontroller`.

Answer (score 5):

You could modify the login screen to remove the "Create New Account" button.  This way existing users can still log in but they have no way to create new accounts.

The file to modify is /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml.  Around line 41 you'll see `<div class="col-1 new-users">`.  Comment out that entire div to hide the New User section of the login page.

Edit:
There is no way to just disable new user registration like you are asking. I did a little more searching, and all I found were several people with the [same](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9350/) [idea](http://wiki.jfusion.org/doku.php?id=magento:disablemagentouserregistration) as mine.  In addition to my original suggestion, I would
a) remove the `<customer_account_create>` section of /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/custom.xml, and
b) remove the registration-related lines from /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml.

Comment: Well this is a simple way to deal with normal users. But for advanced hacker they can do it simply by typing /customer/account/create/ in the url to get into that account creation page. Are there any thorough solutions to eliminate the frontend registration function? by the way, I just don't want to change the .htaccess setting. I just want to handle this small problem in lower level rather than root level.

Comment: You must have a killer store if people are hacking to get in ;-)  Only kidding, I understand you are looking for a clean comprehensive approach.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is one.  See my edits above.

Answer (score 2):

In the above example structure, the controller class name should be changed 
from

class Mycompany_Registrationremove_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController

to

class Mycompany_Registrationremove_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController

Answer (score 1):

Does this method works for **ver. 1.4.1.1**?

Finally I decided to skip all the complicated steps and also modify the **register.phtml** in \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form, apart from the files that BenV said.

I deleted the form and changed the title to "User registration disabled" :)

Comment: Yes, i think this can be good idea with the message showing "Registration is disabled" without unnecessary modification but you need to copy the core file to your theme location like \app\design\frontend\YOUR-THEME\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml for Registration and \app\design\frontend\YOUR-THEME\default\template\customer\form\login.phtml for Login

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of the solutions posted here to work, and found I had to use the following syntax in the config.xml (specifically frontend routers syntax):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mycompany_Registrationremove>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Registrationremove>
</modules>
<global>
    <rewrite>
         <mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_create>
                  <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/create/$#]]></from>
                  <to>/registrationremove/customer_account/create</to>
             </mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_create>
             <mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_createPost>
                 <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/createPost/$#]]></from>
                 <to>/registrationremove/customer_account/createPost</to>
             </mycompany_registrationremove_customer_account_createPost>
       </rewrite> 
</global>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Mycompany_Registrationremove before="Mage_Customer">Mycompany_Registrationremove_Customer</Mycompany_Registrationremove>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

There's more info on this method here - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

Answer (score 0):

One could always change the customer router to point to a module without controllers, e.g.

```
 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <module>MyModule_NullRouting</module>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to liquidity's answer, a couple more changes I'd make to improve this. Firstly the regex doesn't match the url if it does not have a trailing slash eg. `customer/account/create`. To correct, the "from" nodes should read `<![CDATA[#^/customer/account/create(/.*)?$#]]>` and `<![CDATA[#^/customer/account/createPost(/.*)?$#]]>`.

Secondly, I've included an observer that listens for the `customer_registration_is_allowed` event (this gets called in `persistent/customer/form/login.phtml` when using the RWD theme from the `$this->helper('customer')->isRegistrationAllowed()` function):

```
<events>
    <customer_registration_is_allowed>
        <observers>
            <your_module_set_is_active>
                <class>Your_Module_Model_Observers_Customer</class>
                <method>disableCustomerRegistration</method>
            </your_module_set_is_active>
        </observers>
    </customer_registration_is_allowed>
</events>
```

Then in the observer:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Observers_Customer
{
    /**
     * Force disable customer registration
     *
     * @param  Varien_Event_Observer $observer Observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function disableCustomerRegistration($observer)
    {
        $result = $observer->getResult();

        if ($result->getIsAllowed() === true) {
            $result->setIsAllowed(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This sets allowing registration to false and prevents the registration form showing without any template modifications.

Hope this is helpful!